# Security risks of PermitUserEnvironment in ssh

Tags: security, ssh, environment-variables, production-environment

I've read quite a few posts regarding the use of `PermitUserEnvironment` and the file `~/.ssh/environment` in order to pass env variables to an ssh shell. The official [sshd docs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config%205) and a few other resources allude to some security risks of doing this.

```
Enabling environment processing may enable users to bypass access restrictions in some configurations using mechanisms such as LD_PRELOAD.
```

What are the likely security issue of activating `PermitUserEnvironment`? I was looking to hold DB connection details in these environment variables, is this advisable?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's for cases where you restrict the user in some way by using a custom shell - if the user is able to set LD_PRELOAD then they could execute code as their user on the remote machine by intercepting a standard library call.

A simple example of this might be if you disable login for an SFTP-only user by setting their shell to a dynamically linked /bin/false - if they're able to modify ~/.ssh/environment or ~/.ssh/authorized_keys then they could add LD_PRELOAD=nefarious.so

Comment: So it has no impact on regular shell logins where I give the user a regular Bash account? (no sudo)

Comment: Correct, it's only an issue if you're trying to restrict their shell. If you already trust them to execute arbitrary code then letting them set LD_PRELOAD at login time isn't a security issue